# php gd imagerotate fails when -1 is passed for $bgd_color

Tags: php, gd

I had this problem on a client server

```
$tmp = imagerotate($tmp, $angle, -1);
```

$tmp => `bool(false)` with no error message displayed

```
$tmp = imagerotate($tmp, $angle, imagecolorallocatealpha($tmp, 0, 0, 0 , 127));
```

this works fine
$tmp => `resource(89) of type (gd)`

What server configuration variable should be changed to make -1 work ?

```
GD Version: bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
libPNG Version: 1.2.44
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass in -1? The third argument is what color rotate uses for the uncovered section after the rotate. Using -1 as the color does not make sense?

Comment: What kind of image is `$tmp`?  PNG, GIF, JPG?

Comment: -1 means use a transparent color

Comment: @bishop $tmp is created with `imagecreatetruecolor`

Comment: I believe, but I am not 100% sure, that you have to call `imagecolorallocate` (or its alpha companion) for every color you want to have in your image, regardless of whether the image is palette-based or not.  The fact that the color is an `int` is misleading: I don't think it's "any random int" but "an int retrieved through `imagecolorallocate`".  To that point, I think for palette-based image the returned int is an index into the color table, not the twos-complement representation of the RGB.  I'm not near a terminal to check that, though.

Comment: You are right, the right way is to use `imagecolorallocatealpha` for this one but I was just wondering why -1 doesn't work on this server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"What server configuration variable should be changed to make -1 work?"

There is no server configuration variable that makes this work. I ran in to the same issue as you (while using a third party library) and discovered that those who were passing in -1 were pretty much lucky that it did work. Based on my research I believe what happened was one person used this, it worked, and the code just got copied into various projects without a real understanding of it's function. I say this because I see the same exact code, including comments, in various projects.

Later versions of the gd library changed the behavior some, breaking the `imagerotate` function for those who were passing in -1 as the background color.

Anyway, the solution is to use `imagecolorallocatealpha` to add a transparent "color" to the image palette, and pass that color as the background color to `imagerotate`. Your solution of: `$tmp = imagerotate($tmp, $angle, imagecolorallocatealpha($tmp, 0, 0, 0 , 127));` should be just fine.

Comment: Yeah, it became like a wrong/broken convention. `imagecolorallocatealpha` solved it for me. Thank you