# Can anyone please help me in resolving this error?

Tags: php, runtime-error, imagecreatefromjpg

**My Code:**

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>

        <h1>Rotating an Image</h1>

        <?php

        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg("myPic.jpg");
        $imgRotated = imagerotate($img, 45, -1);
        imagejpeg($imgRotated, "myPic.jpg", 100);
        ?>
        <img src="myPic.jpg"/><img src="myPicRotated.jpg">

        </body>
        </html>
```

**Error**

```
Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebsite\index.php on line 11
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `-1` is not a valid value for the third (`bgd_color`) parameter to `imagerotate`...

Comment: And as @Nick already stated, the `-1` causes issues. There is also a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643783/php-gd-imagerotate-fails-when-1-is-passed-for-bgd-color) about this.

Comment: @codedge thanks for pointing out the dupe, I've closed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to [`imagerotate`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagerotate.php) is unsuccessful and returns `false` - see documentation.

That's why `imagejpeg` complains about it.

You can change it to

```php
$imgRotated = imagerotate($img, 45, 0);
```

which should work better.